# Is there anything better than %random%

Tags: windows, batch-file, random

I am writing a program that copies one program infinitely to another location. Here is a part:

```
@echo off
:place
Xcopy C:\Whatever C:\SomethingElse\%random%*
Goto :place
```

Thats it. The asterisk is there so that xcopy assumes it is a file name, not a directory.

Unfortunately, %random% stops somewhere around 32k-37k, and it isn't really random. For my purposes, i need this to really go forever, or at least into the billions. Are there any ways to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Is the randomness important or it should just be uniquely incrementing ? How much random should it be ?

Comment: I would hope that it would randomly name files with a range of 0-1,000,000,000. This is because it only takes about 15 seconds for my file to duplicate 5,000 times. It's a small file. It does not have to be random.

Comment: If randomness is not important, just use an integer that increments by 1: `set /A i+=1` `Xcopy C:\Whatever C:\SomethingElse\%i%*`

Comment: If you find a working solution, note that if the target file name is longer than the source file name, the asterisk could make the operation fail. If you are only copying a file, and there are not any other consideration, maybe you should be using `copy`

Answer (score 0):

Range of %RANDOM% is quite limited.

> %RANDOM% generates a random integer from 0 to 32,767 (inclusive)
>
> 0 ≤ %RANDOM% ≤ 32767

What you could do is use several of them to build a composite path. Something like this:

```
C:\SomethingElse\%random%\%random%\%random%\%random%*
```

Of course, you need to make sure that all parts of the
path exist or else copy won't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try Windows PowerShell [`Get-Random` command](http://www.colorconsole.de/PS_Windows/de/Get-Random.htm). @Sergio Tulentsev is completely right with the limited 16 bit range of the `%random%` command as opposed to the PowerShell command, where the limit is at 32 bit. You should be able to achieve the same in a quite similar way. Additionally piping works better in PowerShell as in the standard command line interface - at least as far as I remember.

I don't know how "good" this random number generator is, but if it is still not random enough, you should consider writing a little command line tool for random numbers. Either your development environment supports "good" random numbers or you can try to implement [XOR-Shift PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift), which is very random in comparison to its implementation effort.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, if randomness is not a requirement, you can use a combination of the current time (at nearest centi-second (10ms)) with some random :

```
 @echo off
 :place
 :: get the current time
 set t=%time%
 :: replace : with _ for file name
 set t=%t::=_%
 Xcopy C:\Whatever C:\SomethingElse\%t%_%random%*
 goto :place
```

However, beware that your script should run faster than the generation of the files. Otherwise you will miss some files.
Moreover, there is no garantee that the random will not provide two times the same number for the same hundredth of a second, even if this is very not likely.

This will allow you to have about 32000 files per centi-sec.

Comment: @Stephan Edited accordingly